# Python FTP Upload with Multiprocessing - Uploaded Files not complete

Tags: python, file-upload, ftp, multiprocessing

i was trying to create a ftp upload with multiprocessing like it is described here in many different ways. The skript already uploads the files I choose but the upload breaks up every time after uploading round about 90 KB. Does anybody has a hint for me what I did wrong ?
Thanks in advance.
Regards Peter

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
from multiprocessing import Process
import os


##### Config für den Upload Path ####
Path='c:/'
#####################################

def uploadZip(zipName,PathUpload):
    # Hochzuladenden XML
    # Upload zu Datenausstausch - Test
    ftpsportschau= FTP('xxxxx')
    ftpsportschau.login ('xxx', 'xxxx')
    zipDatei = open('%s%s' %(PathUpload,zipName),'r')
    try:
       ftpsportschau.storbinary('STOR %s' % zipName, zipDatei)

    except ftplib.error_perm:
       print "PermError: cannot upload file %s" % zipName

    except ftplib.error_temp:
       print "TempError: cannot upload file %s" % zipName

    zipDatei.close()
    ftpsportschau.quit()
    return 

def UploadAsync(FileListe,PathAsync):
    ''' Funktion zum Upload mit parallelen Prozessen
        Sie enthält nicht den Upload Befehl,sondern nur den Aufruf der Prozesse
    '''
    print ' List in Async'+'\n'
    print FileListe

    try:
        for filename in FileListe:
            p = Process(target=uploadZip, args=(filename,PathAsync))
            p.start()

    except:
        print 'An error has occured'

def Files(PathFiles):
    ''' Funktion zum Ermitteln der Files'''
    UploadListe=[]
    Files=os.listdir(PathFiles)
    print Files
    print '\n'
    for files in Files:
        if files.endswith('.zip'):
            UploadListe.append(files)
        else: continue
    print UploadListe
    print '\n'
    return UploadListe

if __name__ == "__main__":
    UploadAsync(Files(Path),Path)
```

Comment: What do you mean "the upload breaks up"? What, precisely, does your script print?

Comment: Hi Rob, the problem was that the script only uploaded the first 90 KBs and stopped without an error notification. The problem was fixed with the binary mode i did not use before while opening the file. My stupid fault. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to "accept" my answer (click the checkmark next to my answer) so others don't spend any more time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be transferring filesin binary format, you should use the `'b'` qualifier in your open:

```
zipDatei = open('%s%s' %(PathUpload,zipName),'rb')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, you were totally right :( I was not able to see that , i don´t know why.
Many thanks.
Regards